# ASP.NET page with status code 404

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

everyone!
I have problem with asp.net error exceptions.
I'm working on real estate web-app and google have made indexes for links on real estates. But after some time period several real estates don't exist anymore in db. 
Problem is next: if user click on link for real estate, which doesn't exist anymore in db, 
I need return my custome error page with status code 404.

I try to do that in next way:

1. on handling url I check if such
   real estate exists
2. if not I throw
   my own `RealEstateDontExistException`
3. in Global.asax in handling error
   of server I check if this error is
   type of `RealEstateDontExistException`
   then
4. I set:

```
Responce.StatusCode = 404;
Server.CleanError();
Server.Transfer("~/ErrorPage.aspx");
```

I need show aspx page with status code 404.
On local host it works fine. But if I try get not existed real estate from production server, then web browser show me next text

> "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
>   with status code 404.

Can someone help me? Thanks .

Comment: did you confirmed that `ErrorPage.aspx` exists on server?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your production web server is showing its own error page. Please configure it (IIS) to show the custom error page on 404 error - see [this article](http://www.braintrove.com/article/46) for how to do that on IIS7 (and [this for IIS 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/80cb8d8d-8fd8-4af5-bb3b-4d11fff3ab9c.mspx?mfr=true)).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your ErrorPage is too small for HTTP 404 in Internet Explorer(should have more than 10 lines).

Have a look at these ressources:

- http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/01/21/important-note-for-your-custom-error-pages/
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/App_5F00_Offline.htm-and-working-around-the-_2200_IE-Friendly-Errors_2200_-feature.aspx

This is the registry-key that the IE uses to determine the minimum size:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\ErrorThresholds
```